# What is the best practice for powerbi data preparation

Tags: powerbi, etl, data-cleaning, powerbi-desktop

With all tools provided in Powerbi for data preparation (etl), I want to know what is the best practice to prepare data :

1- Build an integrated data wharehouse using ssis then connect PowerBI for reports.

2- Use only PowerBI to prepare data and develop reports.

Comment: I don't think is better than another. It just depend on the case. Using ssis and build a data warehouse is better for a considerable amount of data, multiple access to report data from third party apps, thinking on scalability.
But if you have small amount of data and just want some report to show in an area or manager. Just go for Power Bi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to follow the best practice, then you should consider the recommended architecture of a [modern data warehouse](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/solutions/architecture/modern-data-warehouse/):

[image: Modern data warehouse]

It will give you flexibility and scale. Using Power BI only is much more limited and not flexible solution. So something like your option #1 is recommended.

If for some reason you are limited to Power BI only, at least you should consider using [Power BI Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-dataflows-create-use), where to build your model and use it in all your reports later.

Comment: Seems to me this is the best practice to maximize Microsoft product usage. While this may be beneficial to MS monthly cloud services income, you have total lock-in of your data and process into all those (fast changing) fancy MS cloud thingies. I somehow doubt this is will be the best path for many businesses.